# File ownership on docker named volumes

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, file-ownership

I'm having a folder ownership issue when I try to run WordPress on Docker containers. Folders like `wp-content` and `themes` are owned by root, not allowing me to install themes and plugins from the web interface.

#### Goals

- Run WordPress on Docker.
- Obtain a theme from a git repo (owned by us).
- Be able to run WP-CLI from its official Docker image (`wordpress:cli`).
- Be able to install themes and plugins from the web interface.
- Have all files and folders under `/var/www/html` be owned by `www-data` (uid 33).

#### Specs

- Docker version 18.09.5, build e8ff056
- docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
- single container instances for each service - no kubernetes, swarm, stack, etc.
- My [`docker-compose.yml`](https://pastebin.com/dQLgmHgA)
- My `dockerfile` (copied from the git repo):

> `FROM wordpress:5`
>
> `COPY --chown=33 ./ /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme/`

#### Volumes

I don't declare volumes on my dockerfile -- it's only those two lines above, nothing else. In fact, this image exists only to copy a folder into the WordPress image. The WordPress image (which my image derives from) declares a volume in its dockerfile, though.

I do declare volumes on my docker-compose file but when omitting them the issue persists

#### Results

File and folder ownerships...

- when using a [custom image with named volumes](https://pastebin.com/kLTaS7t5)
- when using a [custom image without named volumes](https://pastebin.com/hDq0vDFi)
- when using the [default image with named volumes](https://pastebin.com/yMnrD1j1)
- when using the [default without named volumes](https://pastebin.com/AJhDfHLF)

---

## UPDATE

There's some issue going on with the `COPY` step on the Docker build, but I can't figure out what.

I changed my `dockerfile` to

```
FROM alpine
COPY ./ /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme/
RUN chown -R 33:33 /var/www/html
RUN ls -n /var/www/html
```

If I build from alpine, uid `33` is the owner:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN ls -n /var/www/html
 ---> Running in e9850fa85800
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    1 33       33            4096 Apr 12 19:34 wp-content
```

I change the first line to `FROM wordpress`, **now `root` is the owner**:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN ls -n /var/www/html
 ---> Running in 2810cc37aaba
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 0 0 4096 Apr 12 19:38 wp-content
```

---

How do I proceed to obtain the results that I want (that is, the theme files on `/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme/` and all files and folders owned by `www-data` (uid 33))?

Answer (score -2):

you can set owner using ADD or COPY command in dockerfile, for your COPY command, try `COPY --chown:www-data:www-data ./ /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme/`.

Comment: I'm *already* doing that. It doesn't work. That's exactly the very issue I'm having.

Comment: if you declare it as a volume _before_ doing copy --chown, it won't work, if you reverse the order of operations it should. I can't tell what order you're doing them in here.

Comment: I don't declare volumes on my dockerfile, it's only those two lines from the question, nothing else. The `wordpress` image declares a volume in its dockerfile, though. My image is derived from it -- in fact my image exists only to copy a folder into the WordPress image.

Comment: Try redeclaring it after the copy step, same as base image.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately :(